# GA4 Google Analytics event doesn't appear as conversion

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, react-gtm-module

I'm using  Google Tag Manager(**react-gtm-module)** package) to push custom events to Google Analytics. In code i do it like this:

```
GTM.dataLayer({ dataLayer: { event: 'Custom event' } });
```

Then, in GTM i have trigger for this `Custom event` **(event name is the same everywhere)** and tag which sends event to Google Analytics. Then in GA i marked that event as **conversion**, but when i trigger that event on website it shows up as regular event but not as **conversion**.

This works perfect for every other event but not for this one. I tried to rename event and mark new event as **conversion** but it didn't help.

Could anyone by any chance know the reason why it doesn't work as expected only for this event?

Comment: I have the same problem. I see a given event in Analytics being fired several times in the Reports > Engagement > Events area but it appears with 0 conversions in the Reports > Engagement > Conversions area. Although the event is marked as a conversion... Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: same problem, did anyone find a solution for this @Tiberiu ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure follow the actual issue you are having but you're missing a ' in your code after the event name

this

```
GTM.dataLayer({ dataLayer: { event: 'Custom event } });
```

should change to

```
GTM.dataLayer({ dataLayer: { event: 'Custom event' } });
```

Otherwise, are you saying that you are specifically using the string "Custom event" as the event parameter value? Perhaps that is a reserved value in the system used for something else, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: Oh, that's just a typo in question. In my code all values are valid. And 'Custom event' is just for example. My problem is that this event, marked by me as 'Conversion' doesn't appear as conversion in Google analytics reports